# Apache poi cell formatting

Tags: java, apache-poi, spreadsheet

I am trying to format  a number  2852196 to  $2,852,196  using  Apache poi dataformatter.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
dataFormatter.addFormat("($#,##0_);($#,##0)", numberFormat);
//after adding the above format, i see this format @ index 0, so i have taken 0 in the next line  

String formatCellValue = dataFormatter.formatRawCellContents((Long) cols.get(jj).getValue(), 0, "($#,##0_);($#,##0)");
```

But the output am getting is  USD2,852,196. 
I am missing something or using the incorrect methods.

--
Thanks.

Comment: check this out

http://www.roseindia.net/java/poi/setDataFormat.shtml

Comment: I tried that format,  the content is generated properly in spreadsheet but for -ve numbers its displaying  -$1456  instead of ($1456) as per the financial analysts terminology.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing things like that? Why not just apply the existing format that's already on the cell?

Comment: hmm.. the number should display as a string i.e., $2,852,196  in the Cell, but when we select the cell, it should display as number 2852296 in the formula bar. Thats the Analyst team requirement.

Answer (score 1):

this method change all elements from array of columns

you will call with:

```
protected final static int TYPE_PORCENTAJE = 3;

setTypeColumn(sheet, Arrays.asList(19, 20, 21), TYPE_PORCENTAJE, null);


protected void setTypeColumn(Sheet sheet, List<Integer> columns, int type, Integer format) {
    CellType cellType = CellType.STRING;
    CellStyle style = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    CreationHelper createHelper = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

    switch (type) {
    case TYPE_NUMBER:
        style.setDataFormat(sheet.getWorkbook().createDataFormat().getFormat(BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(1)));
        break;
    case TYPE_MONEY:
        style.setDataFormat(
                sheet.getWorkbook().createDataFormat().getFormat(BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(format)));
        break;
    case TYPE_DATE:
        style.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"));
        break;
    case TYPE_PORCENTAJE:
        style.setDataFormat(sheet.getWorkbook().createDataFormat().getFormat(BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(0xa)));
        break;
    case TYPE_CUSTOM:
        style.setDataFormat(
                sheet.getWorkbook().createDataFormat().getFormat(BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(format)));
        break;
    case TYPE_TEXT:
        style.setDataFormat((short) BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("text"));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    cellType = CellType.NUMERIC;
    final int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    for (int i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns.size(); j++) {
            Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(columns.get(j));
            String value = null;
            if (type == TYPE_TEXT) {
                value = cell.getStringCellValue();
            }
            cell.setCellType(cellType);
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
            if (type == TYPE_PORCENTAJE) {
                cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue() / 100);
            }
            if (type == TYPE_TEXT) {
                style.setWrapText(true);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for the parameter format check this link 
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html